# Ant Design change style Select Component

Tags: reactjs, antd

I wanted to change the `background color` of the `Select` component (not of the dropdown views). 
This is the code I used, but the background does not change, resulting always as default white.

```
class CustomSelect extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
                <Select
                    size="large"
                    style={styles.select}
                    onChange={this.props.onChange}
                >

                    <Option value="male">Male</Option>
                    <Option value="female">Female</Option>
                </Select>
        )
    }

var styles = {
    select: {
        fontSize: "15px", 
        backgroundColor: '#f4f5f7'
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513517/how-to-change-the-style-of-a-ant-design-select-component).

in short,
you need to style inline div with the below class

```
.ant-select-selection {
  background-color: green;
}
```