# React change antd select background color

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I am using React Ant component. I would like to change the background color of Select.

I have followed the method from [How to change the style of a Ant-Design 'Select' component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513517/how-to-change-the-style-of-a-ant-design-select-component). It didn't work if the 'antd/dist/antd.css' was imported. However, it did change the background color of Select if 'antd/dist/antd.css' had not been imported.

How should I change the color with the import of 'antd/dist/antd.css'? The following is the code and css for react

AntdSelect.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Select } from 'antd'
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import  './antd.css'
const { Option } = Select;

function AntdSelect() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Select
                className="ant-select-selection"
                style={{ width: 200 }}>
                <Option value="Daily">Daily</Option>
                <Option value="Weekly">Weekly</Option>
                <Option value="Monthly">Monthly</Option>
                <Option value="Yearly">Yearly</Option>
            </Select>          
        </div>
    )
}

export default AntdSelect
```

antd.css

```
.ant-select-selection {
  background-color: green;
}
```

The objective is to change the background color to green:
[Background green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq8MC.png)

Comment: Please fill in the required code: https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-monad-evy62 fork and provide the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The className which you're looking for is `ant-select-selection-search`

```
.ant-select-selection-search {
  background-color: green;
}
```

### SOLVING STEPS

1. Open up your inspector and point to the input.
2. See the className which governs the input. In this example, it's `ant-select-selection-search`
3. Change the background color in your css.
4. If you see no changes, add `!important`.

Comment: I am used to use Firefox, and do not immediately understand the meaning of "Open up your inspector", it turned out it means the inspector in Chrome. Thanks for the very useful hint.